# Custom Post index page displaying all Custom Post's - without slug conflict

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, wordpress, slug

I usually code in Ruby on Rails where each model has "Show" pages and "Index" pages. I am now re-creating a website in Wordpress (based on an old RoR-site) using Custom Post for each model.

I have, for example, a model named Review. In Rails if Reviews have the slug /reviews then each Review will have a url like /reviews/this-review and at the url /reviews all the Reviews can/will be listed.

It seems like in Wordpress with Custom Posts I choose a similar slug /reviews for a Custom Post which creates each review as /reviews/this-review or /reviews/123 (which is fine) but there is no index page created where I can display all reviews on /reviews.

I have solved this by creating a Page called Reviews with that slug (/reviews). There is no conflict when I add the Page but if I update the Custom Post it complains about the slug already being used.

What is the typical way of solving this in Wordpress so that I can show all Reviews (Custom Posts) on one page without slug conflicts?

Comment: This is the `archive` page. `archive-reviews.php` should be the name of the file to display all `review` posts. Otherwise it could by any page which has a custom query ( a query that brings `review` custom posts ) . If you create this `.php` there is no need to create a page called "reviews"

Comment: Thanks, does this also mean that if there is a file called archive-reviews.php this will automatically be found at /reviews ? The slug issue is the main issue here and I want either archive-page there is to be found at /reviews

Comment: Yes, it will be found at /reviews but delete the page otherwise there will be a conflict with the slugs. Try creating an archive-reviews.php and insert just a `<p>hi</p>` to see that it will be shown and play with it

Comment: I have tried this and it works but it is not really an optimal solution as it keeps content in the code. Is this really the best/optimal solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "_keeps content in the code_"?

Comment: I meant that if I want to write an intro description (typed content/text) I have to do that in the php-code/php-file and not in the database - where content belongs. Do you understand what I mean with this, and is it possible to change this behavior?